# Rails - decompressing HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, thin, webrick, http-compression

Is there some way to decompress HTTP **request** (sent from mobile phone) on server side? Will be this done using Ruby, or server's means makes no difference.

Servers planned to use are: Webrick, Thin and Apache2.

I am planning to compress request in my own Android and iOS applications, so I'm free to choose compression method.

Comment: Is there a reason why you ain't wanting to use the standard http compression functionality provided by pretty much every http server and client?

Comment: The reason is that I do not know about HTTP compression in Webrick and Thin, and my colleagues reported that they discovered that Apache was unable to decompress incoming request.